# Google Analytics: Show online User ID's in Active User Report

Tags: android, google-analytics

Currently under Active Reports of GA dashboard, theres only report of number of active users in a day/wee/year. I need a report where I can check which all user where active for the specific day. I am setting the user id during GA initialization.

So is it possible to get me a list of all user ids which had open the app on specific day/wee/year.

Tks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying out Heap Analytics or Intercom.io. There are plenty of analytics programs that do user tracking, such as MixPanel. Heap, however, offers automatic event tracking, where user interactions are captured automatically without any code.

Comment: I am working on a project which already uses GA. Is there a way to track uid's in GA since we can set uid during initialization explicitly?

Comment: From my understanding, GA focuses on providing more "grouped" data rather than showing you personalized analytics. Hence,  my recommendation on using additional analytics programs that will provide individual reporting (ex:  all user where active for the specific day) https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123663

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong in that this is the data that you're looking for - https://www.intercom.io/customer-intelligence